# Rails6 RSS出力でのページid表示の件

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rssでページ番号を取得できません。
解決方法を教えて下さい。

**RSSでの表示**
http://localhost:3000/articles/feed

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>1Kエクストリーム：更新情報</title>
        <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/</link>
        <description>1Kエクストリーム ブログ：新着</description>
            <item>
                <title>キャベツ</title>
                <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/articles/#{article.id}</link>
                <description>tesyqqqqqqqqqqq</description>
                <pubDate>2022-11-27 09:18:24 +0900</pubDate>
            </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

#{article.id}の箇所ですが、articleのidを表示したいですが
#{article.id}がテキストでそのまま表示されてしまいます。
以下のようにidの番号を取得したいです

```
 <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/articles/80</link>
```

viewとcontrollerは下記のように設定してます。

views/articles/feed.rss.erb

```
<rss version='2.0'>
    <channel>
        <title>1Kエクストリーム：更新情報</title>
        <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/</link>
        <description>1Kエクストリーム ブログ：新着</description>

        <% @articles.each do |article| %>
            <item>
                <title><%= article.title %></title>
                <link>https://www.onekextreme.com/articles/#{article.id}</link>
                <description><%= article.content1 %></description>
                <pubDate><%= article.created_at %></pubDate>
            </item>
         <% end %>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def feed
  @articles = Article.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(6)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<link>https://www.onekextreme.com/articles/<%= article.id %></link>
```

URLヘルパーを使うなら

```
<link><%= article_url(article) %></link>
```